Linear Triatomic Molecule
I am self-studying classical mechanics from the 3rd edition of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics. Right now, I'm working on Chapter 6, Problem 5, in which we are asked to consider a linear triatomic molecule approximated by a mass $m$ on either side of a mass $M$, each mass $m$ connected to $M$ by a spring of constant $k$.

(a) In the linear triatomic molecule, suppose the initial condition is that the center atom is at rest but displaced by an amount $a_{0}$ from equilibrium, the other two being at their equilibrium points. Find the amplitudes of the longitudinal small oscillations about the center of mass. Give the amplitudes of the normal modes.


(b) Repeat part (a) but with the center atom initially at its equilibrium position but with an initial speed $v_{0}$.

To do these, I begin by writing down the solution in the small-angle approximation to the equations of motion for the displacements from equilibrium of the atoms, $\eta_{1}$, $\eta_{2}$, and $\eta_{3}$, which are of the form
\begin{align*}
\eta_{1}(t) &= C_{1}a_{31}\cos{(\delta_{1})} + C_{2}a_{12}\cos{(\omega_{2}t+\delta_{2})} + C_{3}a_{33}\cos{(\omega_{3}t+\delta_{3})}\\
\eta_{2}(t) &= C_{1}a_{31}\cos{(\delta_{1})} - \frac{2m}{M}C_{3}a_{33}\cos{(\omega_{3}t+\delta_{3})}\\
\eta_{3}(t) &= C_{1}a_{31}\cos{(\delta_{1})} - C_{2}a_{12}\cos{(\omega_{2}t+\delta_{2})}+ C_{3}a_{33}\cos{(\omega_{3}t+\delta_{3})}
\end{align*}
where $a_{ij}$ corresponds to the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ entry of the eigenvector $\mathbf{a}_{j}$ with accompanying eigenfrequency $\omega_{i}$; $\omega_{1} = 0$, $\omega_{2} = \sqrt{k/m}$, and $\omega_{3} = \sqrt{k(M+2m)/(mM)}$.
This much is effectively given in the text on pp. 253-257. All that's left is to solve for the real constants $C_{i}$ and $\delta_{i}$ given the initial conditions. This is straightforward in (a), but I'm having trouble doing so in (b). I interpret (b) to mean that $\eta_{i}(0) =\dot{\eta}_{1}(0) = \dot{\eta}_{3}(0) = 0$ and $\dot{\eta}_{2}(0) = v_{0}\neq 0$. In this case, the system that results is
\begin{align*}
C_{1}a_{31}\cos{(\delta_{1})} + C_{2}a_{12}\cos{(\delta_{2})} + C_{3}a_{33}\cos{(\delta_{3})}&=0\\
C_{1}a_{31}\cos{(\delta_{1})} - \frac{2m}{M}C_{3}a_{33}\cos{(\delta_{3})}&=0\\
C_{1}a_{31}\cos{(\delta_{1})} - C_{2}a_{12}\cos{(\delta_{2})}+ C_{3}a_{33}\cos{(\delta_{3})}&=0\\
-\omega_{2} C_{2}a_{12}\sin{(\delta_{2})} - \omega_{3}C_{3}a_{33}\sin{(\delta_{3})}&=0\\
\omega_{3}\frac{2m}{M}C_{3}a_{33}\sin{(\delta_{3})}&=v_{0}\\
\omega_{2} C_{2}a_{12}\sin{(\delta_{2})} - \omega_{3}C_{3}a_{33}\sin{(\delta_{3})}&=0
\end{align*}
But the last three of these equations are inconsistent: the fourth and sixth imply that $C_{3}a_{33}\sin{(\delta_{3})} = 0$ but the fifth requires $C_{3}a_{33}\sin{(\delta_{3})}\neq 0$.
Am I misunderstanding the physics of the problem? Does a non-zero initial velocity of the center atom imply non-zero initial velocities for the other two atoms? If this is the case, is it correct to assume that the left and right atoms move with identical velocities $v_{1}$ and then use conservation of linear momentum to solve for $v_{1}$ in terms of $m$, $M$, and $v_{0}$? Since the springs do not impart a force at the instant $t = 0$, I don't see physically why the masses $m$ should have initial velocities though. Still, this seems to be the only way to make the equations consistent.
